# Neo4J Data Model

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

I'm new to Neo4J and I have a question about the most appropriate data model for a the problem domain described below.

## Background

As I understand it, in Neo4J every relationship has a direction of sorts, outgoing, incoming or undirected. I read that a common mistake newbies make in "bi-directional" relationships is that they might model the relationship in both directions where in reality one undirected relationship would serve the purpose well. I also understand that irrespective of the direction it is possible at query time to ignore it and query based on either side of the relationship.

## Problem Domain

This is a bit cliché, but stick with me, in a graph where "People" can connect with one another I felt tempted to model that as an undirected relationship. However, perhaps in my problem domain I want to store meta data on the relationship edge rather than at either of the People nodes. E.g. timestamp of when then connected or type of relationship (friend, family, employer etc...). Perhaps this is a "side effect" of using the spring-data-neo4j libraries but it seems that if I wish to data meta data on the edge rather than at the node I must create a class which is annotated as `@RelationshipEntity` rather than `@NodeEntity`. This necessitates a `@StartNode` and `@EndNode` which then seems to imply a direction to my otherwise undirected relationship...

Now, as it turns out this might not be a bad thing in my case because perhaps after all it turns out there is something useful about this additional directed context (e.g. perhaps I want to know who initiated the relationship so that the target node (person) must accept the invitation to be friends).

Now imagine that each person can place the "relationship" into a "group" like "friends, family, colleagues" etc I feel like I'd now need to actually have two distinct edges that point in either direction so that the meta data specific to the given direction has a natural place to reside. But this seems to have been described as a newbie anti-pattern.

## Questions

I have two questions:

1) Should I use two separate distinct relationship edges that essentially point either way as a bi-directional relationship if I need to store meta data that is specific to the direction. e.g. `Person A <--> Person B` but person A placed Person B in the friends group whereas Person B placed A in the colleagues group.

2) Given the Java data model below, I am unclear what the direction attribute on the `@Relationship` annotation of `Person` should be. If I specify nothing it default to `OUTGOING`. But since it's a reflective relationship depending on which person instance you look at the relationship could be either outgoing or incoming, e.g. if person A adds person B, both are Person instances, but the direction is outgoing on the person A instance and incoming on the person B instance. Should the annotation be omitted altogether since I'm using a `@RelationshipEntity`?

## Java Data Model

```
@NodeEntity
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class Person {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

... other attributes

    @Relationship(type = "CONNECTION_OF", direction = UNDIRECTED)
    private Set<Connection> connections;
}






@Data
@RelationshipEntity(type = "CONNECTION_OF")
public class Connection {

    @GraphId
    private Long relationshipId;

... other meta-data

    @StartNode
    private Person from;

    @EndNode
    private Person to;
}
```

Comment: For your first question my answer is yes, you can do it. It depends only of your domain. If your domain requires that you use separated relationships with the same type and specific meta data between the same nodes, fine. If not, fine too! The problem occurs when we create not necessary relationships between  same nodes to store the same properties and with the same semantic. Unfortunately i'm not able to answer your second question.

Answer (score 1):

1) The rule of thumb that works well is to answer a question - if a relationship from A to B exists, can another relationship from B to A still be created, with different metadata? And can you delete one direction of the relationship independently of the other?

If the answer is yes they go for two directed relationships, otherwise stay with `UNDIRECTED`, and create `initiatedBy=userId` property or similar.

For your case where you put connections into groups - the thing is that you really categorize the people from another person's view, maybe it is a completely different fact independent of the `CONNECTED_TO` relationship?

You could e.g. create a group node and link that to owner and all people in the group, with following schema:

```
(:Person)-[:OWNS]-(:Group)-[:CATEGORIZED]-(:Person)
```

2) Keep the `@Relationship(type = "CONNECTION_OF", direction = UNDIRECTED)`. For a given person X the `connections` Set is going to have elements that have from=X for outgoing edges mixed with elements that have to=X for incoming. All of these will be mixed in one collection.